# How To Get LinkedIn Return URL after Authentication

Tags: python, authentication, linkedin-api, urllib

I am trying to use https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
    API_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'
    authentication = LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
    print authentication.authorization_url
```

This code prints:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_share&state=1e7f21566bdd75cee5d71d0615f338ad&redirect_uri=http%3A//localhost%3A8080&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX
```

When I click this link, LinkedIn authentication page is opening. After authentication, it returns that URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/?code=CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC&state=f40c8d9ec67df057e72eeb235f4d8e7c
```

If I copy that CCCCCCCC... code quickly and use it in

```
application = LinkedInApplication(authentication)

authentication.authorization_code = "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"

application = LinkedInApplication(token=authentication.get_access_token())

print application.get_profile()
```

it prints the profile information that I need. But I don't want to click to URL and copy that CCCCC... code into my python code. I want to do these programmatically. I need to get that authorization_code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I run into an invalid redirect_uri error when I follow the link that I get, so I can only help you get started.

If the code was on the page you are linked to, you could simply HTTP GET the page and extract the code. However, since you say you must load the page in your browser, authenticate yourself, then get the code from the resulting page, the process is a bit more complicated. Can you try a GET on the page with your credentials already included?

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
    API_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'
    authentication = LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
    auth_url = authentication.authorization_url

    #Create an HTTP request with your credentials included
    response = requests.get(auth_url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
    print response
    print response.text
```

This is just to get you started. I believe that authenticating yourself programmatically is possible, but it may be slightly more complicated than this basic approach. Let me know what this returns for you.

Comment: It prints html code of authorization page. It won't login. Actually it does not need to login automatically. I just need the URL that returns from authorization.

Comment: When you log in manually, what is the resulting action? Can you get that URL? Parameters? You're going to have to play around with this a little...